# Can't Open DFLIB.mod

Tags: fortran, gfortran

I have received a Fortran code (.f90), which uses DFLIB:

`use DFlib`

I am trying to compile the code on Ubuntu 18.04 using gfortran compiler. But, the compilation gets terminated by:

`Can't open module file ‘dflib.mod’ for reading at (1): No such file or directory`

After Googling, it seems DFLIB is supported on Windows (only?). Is there anyway to compile the code on Ubuntu with gfortran?

Comment: Welcome, use tag [tag:fortran], Fortran 90 is just one old version. Did you install DFLIB? If not, it is no wonder it fails.

Comment: Like what @VladimirF says.  Also, DFLIB is quite an old bit of software these days and the 'best' thing to do is probably to remove the dependency on it.  Of course, I haven't a clue how easy that would be for you.

Comment: DFLIB comes from DEC Visual Fortran (DVF), which then became CVF and is now called IVF (Intel Visual Fortran).  DVF was formerly MS fortran: hence Windows only.  This post from the Intel site https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/intel-visual-fortran-compiler-for-windows/topic/275782 tells you what the Intel replacements are.

Comment: @VladimirF How can I install DFLIB? Could you please give some guidance about install it on my Linux machine? I appreciate it in advance.